# Unable to run Docker without sudo on AMI linux EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am unable to run Docker on AMI linux EC2 instance on AWS. My AMI linux instance is `Linux ip-172-31-29-77 4.14.62-65.117.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 10 20:03:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I am able to install docker and start the service using:

```
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user
```

but cmd `docker ps` does not work?

can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,
Nidhi Arora

Answer (score 7):

You have done all the steps correctly. I believe your goal here is to run docker commands without sudo.

However after adding user to the docker (Or any) group, **you have to refresh the user's group id**.

You can either login again or do `su - $USER`.

You can run `id` before and after to confirm.

Comment: Victor you saved my life, that worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

On Amazon Linux, if you do not know the password of ec2-user, just restart the EC2 instance to refresh the addition of ec2-user  to the 'docker' group.